# merge array data with array data but only certain number like from array 1 - 5 assign a then 6-9 assign b

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good afternoon
I'm trying to merge 2 object by assigning some values to a number of element the other number to another number of elements. I managed to create some thing but it places some on the wrong position an the code is repetitive.
Here is my code

```
const data = [
  [
      "Greece"
  ],
  [
      "Denmark"
  ],
  [
      "Finland"
  ],
  [
      "Norway"
  ],
  [
      "Sweden"
  ],
  [
      "Portugal"
  ],
  [
      "Austria"
  ],
  [
      "Belgium"
  ],
  [
      "Bulgaria"
  ],
  [
      "Croatia"
  ],
  [
      "Cyprus"
  ],
  [
      "Czech Republic"
  ],
  [
      "Estonia"
  ],
  [
      "France"
  ],
  [
      "Germany (Federal Republic of)"
  ],
  [
      "Gibraltar"
  ],
  [
      "Hungary"
  ],
  [
      "Iceland"
  ],
  [
      "Ireland"
  ],
  [
      "Italy"
  ],
  [
      "Latvia"
  ],
  [
      "Liechtenstein"
  ],
  [
      "Lithuania"
  ],
  [
      "Luxembourg"
  ],
  [
      "Malta"
  ],
  [
      "Netherlands"
  ],
  [
      "Poland"
  ],
  [
      "Reunion"
  ],
  [
      "Romania"
  ],
  [
      "Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Collectivité territoriale de la République française)"
  ],
  [
      "Slovak Republic"
  ],
  [
      "Slovenia"
  ],
  [
      "Spain"
  ],
  [
      "Switzerland"
  ],
  [
      "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"
  ],
  [
      "Kazakhstan"
  ],
  [
      "Turkey"
  ],
  [
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
  ],
  [
      "Faroe Islands"
  ],
  [
      "Israel"
  ],
  [
      "Macau"
  ],
  [
      "Azerbaijan"
  ],
  [
      "Guadeloupe"
  ],
  [
      "Fiji"
  ],
  [
      "Samoa"
  ],
  [
      "Tonga"
  ],
  [
      "Canada"
  ],
  [
      "United States of America"
  ],
  [
      "Monaco"
  ],
  [
      "Bermuda"
  ],
  [
      "Costa Rica"
  ],
  [
      "Guatemala"
  ],
  [
      "Guyana"
  ],
  [
      "Honduras"
  ],
  [
      "Papua New Guinea"
  ],
  [
      "Paraguay"
  ],
  [
      "Albania"
  ],
  [
      "Cambodia"
  ],
  [
      "Sri Lanka"
  ],
  [
      "Dominican Republic"
  ],
  [
      "Ecuador"
  ],
  [
      "Mongolia"
  ],
  [
      "Nicaragua"
  ],
  [
      "Vietnam"
  ],
  [
      "Jordan"
  ],
  [
      "Namibia"
  ],
  [
      "Afghanistan"
  ],
  [
      "Argentina"
  ],
  [
      "Botswana"
  ],
  [
      "Cameroon"
  ],
  [
      "Congo"
  ],
  [
      "Cote d'Ivoire"
  ],
  [
      "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"
  ],
  [
      "Ghana"
  ],
  [
      "Guinea"
  ],
  [
      "Guinea-Bissau"
  ],
  [
      "Kosovo"
  ],
  [
      "Liberia"
  ],
  [
      "Madagascar"
  ],
  [
      "Moldova"
  ],
  [
      "Nigeria"
  ],
  [
      "Republic of Rwanda"
  ],
  [
      "Senegal"
  ],
  [
      "Somalia"
  ],
  [
      "South Africa"
  ],
  [
      "Swaziland"
  ],
  [
      "Syrian Arab Republic"
  ],
  [
      "Uganda"
  ],
  [
      "Zambia"
  ],
  [
      "Mexico"
  ],
  [
      "Andorra"
  ],
  [
      "Belarus"
  ],
  [
      "Greenland (Denmark)"
  ],
  [
      "Montenegro"
  ],
  [
      "Serbia"
  ],
  [
      "Sierra Leone"
  ],
  [
      "The Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia"
  ],
  [
      "Ukraine"
  ],
  [
      "Russian Federation"
  ],
  [
      "Burkina Faso"
  ],
  [
      "Central African Republic"
  ],
  [
      "Niger"
  ],
  [
      "Democratic Republic of Congo"
  ],
  [
      "Armenia"
  ],
  [
      "Philippines"
  ],
  [
      "China"
  ],
  [
      "Gabon"
  ],
  [
      "Malawi"
  ],
  [
      "Japan"
  ],
  [
      "Kenya"
  ],
  [
      "Kyrgyzstan"
  ],
  [
      "Panama"
  ],
  [
      "Bangladesh"
  ],
  [
      "Georgia"
  ],
  [
      "Pakistan"
  ],
  [
      "Singapore"
  ],
  [
      "Chad"
  ],
  [
      "Indonesia"
  ],
  [
      "El Salvador"
  ],
  [
      "Algeria"
  ],
  [
      "Bahrain"
  ],
  [
      "Benin"
  ],
  [
      "Brunei Darussalam"
  ],
  [
      "Iran"
  ],
  [
      "Laos"
  ],
  [
      "Malaysia"
  ],
  [
      "Mali"
  ],
  [
      "Togo"
  ],
  [
      "Uzbekistan"
  ],
  [
      "Tanzania"
  ],
  [
      "Thailand"
  ],
  [
      "Mauritius"
  ],
  [
      "Anguilla"
  ],
  [
      "Antigua and Barbuda"
  ],
  [
      "Barbados"
  ],
  [
      "British Virgin Islands"
  ],
  [
      "Cayman Islands"
  ],
  [
      "Dominica"
  ],
  [
      "Grenada"
  ],
  [
      "Jamaica"
  ],
  [
      "Montserrat"
  ],
  [
      "Saint Kitts and Nevis"
  ],
  [
      "Saint Lucia"
  ],
  [
      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"
  ],
  [
      "Virgin Islands"
  ],
  [
      "Tunisia"
  ],
  [
      "Chile"
  ],
  [
      "Australia"
  ],
  [
      "Cabo Verde"
  ],
  [
      "Curaçao"
  ],
  [
      "Myanmar"
  ],
  [
      "Gambia"
  ],
  [
      "Brazil"
  ],
  [
      "Suriname"
  ],
  [
      "Trinidad and Tobago"
  ],
  [
      "Qatar"
  ],
  [
      "Seychelles"
  ],
  [
      "Burundi"
  ],
  [
      "French Polynesia"
  ],
  [
      "Haiti"
  ],
  [
      "Bolivia"
  ],
  [
      "Belize"
  ],
  [
      "Hong Kong"
  ],
  [
      "Taiwan"
  ],
  [
      "Kuwait"
  ],
  [
      "Zimbabwe"
  ],
  [
      "Nepal"
  ],
  [
      "New Zealand"
  ],
  [
      "Egypt"
  ],
  [
      "Angola"
  ],
  [
      "Lesotho"
  ],
  [
      "Mozambique"
  ],
  [
      "Puerto Rico"
  ],
  [
      "Peru"
  ],
  [
      "Equatorial Guinea"
  ],
  [
      "Uruguay"
  ],
  [
      "Venezuela"
  ],
  [
      "India"
  ],
  [
      "Maldives"
  ],
  [
      "Republic of Korea"
  ],
  [
      "Turkmenistan"
  ],
  [
      "Tajikistan"
  ],
  [
      "Cuba"
  ],
  [
      "Saudi Arabia"
  ],
  [
      "Timor-Leste"
  ],
  [
      "Iraq"
  ],
  [
      "Libya"
  ],
  [
      "Mauritania"
  ],
  [
      "Morocco"
  ],
  [
      "Republic of Djibouti"
  ],
  [
      "Sudan"
  ],
  [
      "Lebanon"
  ],
  [
      "Oman"
  ],
  [
      "United Arab Emirates"
  ],
  [
      "Yemen"
  ]
];

const preset = [
  {
    "zone": 5821,
    "count": 36
  },
  {
    "zone": 5822,
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "zone": 5823,
    "count": 53
  },
  {
    "zone": 5824,
    "count": 28
  },
  {
    "zone": 5825,
    "count": 27
  },
  {
    "zone": 5826,
    "count": 16
  },
  {
    "zone": 5827,
    "count": 23
  }
];

const myArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < preset.length; i++) {
  for (let t = 0; t < preset[i].count; t++) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[i].zone,
      country: data[t][0],
      number: i + 1
    });
  }
}
```

It produces the following results.

```
[ { zone: 5821, country: 'Greece', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Denmark', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Finland', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Norway', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Sweden', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Portugal', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Austria', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Belgium', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Croatia', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Cyprus', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Estonia', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'France', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Hungary', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Iceland', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Ireland', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Italy', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Latvia', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Liechtenstein', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Lithuania', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Luxembourg', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Malta', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Netherlands', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Poland', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Reunion', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Romania', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821,
    country: 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Collectivité territoriale de la République française)',
    number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Slovak Republic', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Slovenia', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Spain', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Switzerland', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821,
    country: 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland',
    number: 1 },
  { zone: 5821, country: 'Kazakhstan', number: 1 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Greece', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Denmark', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Finland', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Norway', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Sweden', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Portugal', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Austria', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Belgium', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Croatia', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Cyprus', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5822, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 2 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Greece', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Denmark', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Finland', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Norway', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Sweden', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Portugal', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Austria', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Belgium', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Croatia', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Cyprus', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Estonia', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'France', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Hungary', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Iceland', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Ireland', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Italy', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Latvia', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Liechtenstein', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Lithuania', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Luxembourg', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Malta', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Netherlands', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Poland', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Reunion', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Romania', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823,
    country: 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Collectivité territoriale de la République française)',
    number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Slovak Republic', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Slovenia', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Spain', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Switzerland', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823,
    country: 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland',
    number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Kazakhstan', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Turkey', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Faroe Islands', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Israel', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Macau', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Azerbaijan', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Guadeloupe', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Fiji', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Samoa', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Tonga', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Canada', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'United States of America', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Monaco', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Bermuda', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Costa Rica', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Guatemala', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5823, country: 'Guyana', number: 3 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Greece', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Denmark', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Finland', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Norway', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Sweden', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Portugal', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Austria', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Belgium', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Croatia', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Cyprus', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Estonia', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'France', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Hungary', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Iceland', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Ireland', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Italy', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Latvia', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Liechtenstein', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Lithuania', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Luxembourg', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Malta', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Netherlands', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Poland', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5824, country: 'Reunion', number: 4 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Greece', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Denmark', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Finland', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Norway', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Sweden', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Portugal', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Austria', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Belgium', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Croatia', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Cyprus', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Estonia', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'France', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Hungary', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Iceland', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Ireland', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Italy', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Latvia', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Liechtenstein', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Lithuania', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Luxembourg', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Malta', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Netherlands', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5825, country: 'Poland', number: 5 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Greece', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Denmark', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Finland', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Norway', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Sweden', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Portugal', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Austria', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Belgium', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Croatia', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Cyprus', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Estonia', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'France', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 6 },
  { zone: 5826, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 6 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Greece', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Denmark', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Finland', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Norway', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Sweden', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Portugal', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Austria', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Belgium', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Bulgaria', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Croatia', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Cyprus', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Czech Republic', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Estonia', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'France', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827,
    country: 'Germany (Federal Republic of)',
    number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Gibraltar', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Hungary', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Iceland', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Ireland', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Italy', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Latvia', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Liechtenstein', number: 7 },
  { zone: 5827, country: 'Lithuania', number: 7 } ]
```

As you can see zone: 5820 is assigned to Iraq but it is not supposed to do that. I would like some help.

Expected results each zone is supposed to be assigned to with countries from index 0 to 35 which is the count element in the preset but It repeats and I see the issue I just can't figure it out.
My plan was for each zone loop count times and assign countries but I didn't foresee that it will start from index 0 every count

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Comment: example zone 5821 should start from Greece to Kazakhstan then zone 5822  from Turkey to United States of America and so forth

Comment: I've added an answer now. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I just saw it and its working great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#flatMap` and store the current index in a closure.

```js
const data=[["Greece"],["Denmark"],["Finland"],["Norway"],["Sweden"],["Portugal"],["Austria"],["Belgium"],["Bulgaria"],["Croatia"],["Cyprus"],["Czech Republic"],["Estonia"],["France"],["Germany (Federal Republic of)"],["Gibraltar"],["Hungary"],["Iceland"],["Ireland"],["Italy"],["Latvia"],["Liechtenstein"],["Lithuania"],["Luxembourg"],["Malta"],["Netherlands"],["Poland"],["Reunion"],["Romania"],["Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Collectivit\xe9 territoriale de la R\xe9publique fran\xe7aise)"],["Slovak Republic"],["Slovenia"],["Spain"],["Switzerland"],["United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"],["Kazakhstan"],["Turkey"],["Bosnia and Herzegovina"],["Faroe Islands"],["Israel"],["Macau"],["Azerbaijan"],["Guadeloupe"],["Fiji"],["Samoa"],["Tonga"],["Canada"],["United States of America"],["Monaco"],["Bermuda"],["Costa Rica"],["Guatemala"],["Guyana"],["Honduras"],["Papua New Guinea"],["Paraguay"],["Albania"],["Cambodia"],["Sri Lanka"],["Dominican Republic"],["Ecuador"],["Mongolia"],["Nicaragua"],["Vietnam"],["Jordan"],["Namibia"],["Afghanistan"],["Argentina"],["Botswana"],["Cameroon"],["Congo"],["Cote d'Ivoire"],["Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"],["Ghana"],["Guinea"],["Guinea-Bissau"],["Kosovo"],["Liberia"],["Madagascar"],["Moldova"],["Nigeria"],["Republic of Rwanda"],["Senegal"],["Somalia"],["South Africa"],["Swaziland"],["Syrian Arab Republic"],["Uganda"],["Zambia"],["Mexico"],["Andorra"],["Belarus"],["Greenland (Denmark)"],["Montenegro"],["Serbia"],["Sierra Leone"],["The Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia"],["Ukraine"],["Russian Federation"],["Burkina Faso"],["Central African Republic"],["Niger"],["Democratic Republic of Congo"],["Armenia"],["Philippines"],["China"],["Gabon"],["Malawi"],["Japan"],["Kenya"],["Kyrgyzstan"],["Panama"],["Bangladesh"],["Georgia"],["Pakistan"],["Singapore"],["Chad"],["Indonesia"],["El Salvador"],["Algeria"],["Bahrain"],["Benin"],["Brunei Darussalam"],["Iran"],["Laos"],["Malaysia"],["Mali"],["Togo"],["Uzbekistan"],["Tanzania"],["Thailand"],["Mauritius"],["Anguilla"],["Antigua and Barbuda"],["Barbados"],["British Virgin Islands"],["Cayman Islands"],["Dominica"],["Grenada"],["Jamaica"],["Montserrat"],["Saint Kitts and Nevis"],["Saint Lucia"],["Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"],["Virgin Islands"],["Tunisia"],["Chile"],["Australia"],["Cabo Verde"],["Cura\xe7ao"],["Myanmar"],["Gambia"],["Brazil"],["Suriname"],["Trinidad and Tobago"],["Qatar"],["Seychelles"],["Burundi"],["French Polynesia"],["Haiti"],["Bolivia"],["Belize"],["Hong Kong"],["Taiwan"],["Kuwait"],["Zimbabwe"],["Nepal"],["New Zealand"],["Egypt"],["Angola"],["Lesotho"],["Mozambique"],["Puerto Rico"],["Peru"],["Equatorial Guinea"],["Uruguay"],["Venezuela"],["India"],["Maldives"],["Republic of Korea"],["Turkmenistan"],["Tajikistan"],["Cuba"],["Saudi Arabia"],["Timor-Leste"],["Iraq"],["Libya"],["Mauritania"],["Morocco"],["Republic of Djibouti"],["Sudan"],["Lebanon"],["Oman"],["United Arab Emirates"],["Yemen"]],preset=[{zone:5821,count:36},{zone:5822,count:12},{zone:5823,count:53},{zone:5824,count:28},{zone:5825,count:27},{zone:5826,count:16},{zone:5827,count:23}];
const res = preset.flatMap((c => (o, i) => data.slice(c, c += o.count).map(x => ({
    zone: o.zone,
    country: x[0],
    number: i + 1
})))(0));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it supposed to do then?

From Your code below

```
if (**i <= 2**) {
myArr.push({
  zone: preset[0].zone,
  country: data[i][0],
  number: 1
});
}
```

Above will run for i = 0, 1 and 2, which is Saudi, Timor and Iraq. If you want all of the zones to only be applied to two items, then change your if logic to say below

```
if (i <= 1) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[0].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 1
    });
  } 
  else if (i > 1 && i <= 3) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[1].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 2
    });
  }
  else if (i > 3 && i <= 5) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[2].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 3
    });
  }
  else if (i > 5 && i <= 7) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[3].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 4
    });
  }
  else if (i > 7 && i <= 9) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[4].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 5
    });
  }
  else if (i > 9 && i <= 11) {
    myArr.push({
      zone: preset[5].zone,
      country: data[i][0],
      number: 6
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("TEST");
  }
```

You can also simplify the entire thing to say

```
index = Math.floor(i/2)
myArr.push({
  zone: preset[index].zone,
  country: data[i][0],
  number: index+1
});
```